# How to remove entity from collection when it was deleted

Tags: c#, collections

I have `Entity` class and it has `IsEntityDeleted` property and `DeleteEntity` method:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual bool IsEntityDeleted { get; internal set; }

    public void DeleteEntity()
    {
        // Other logics...
        IsEntityDeleted = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see `IsEntityDeleted` will be true when I call `DeleteEntity` method. In many places I have many collections. I don't want to keep deleted entities to collection. Collection class is custom:

```
public class MyVirtualCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Entity
{
    ICollection<T> Items { get; set; }

    public MyVirtualCollection(ICollection<T> source)
    {
        Items = source;
    }
    public int Count => Items.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => Items.IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return Items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return Items.Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Here is use case:

```
var firstEntity = new Entity();
var secondEntity = new Entity();

var list = new List<Entity>();
list.Add(firstEntity);
list.Add(secondEntity);

MyVirtualCollection<Entity> entities = new MyVirtualCollection<Entity>(list); // entities.Count is 2 here

firstEntity.DeleteEntity(); // entities.Count should be 1

secondEntity.DeleteEntity(); // entities.Count should be 0
```

Is it possible to delete entity from `MyVirtualCollection` collections when `IsEntityDeleted` becomes true?

Comment: @Dllshod  Why can not you use Remove method itself to remove item  as ICollection implements the Add() and Remove() methods.

Comment: @SteadyReader, Because there are a lot of collections and don't want to call Remove for each collection. I want to Remove it automatically

Comment: @Dllshod, so you want to remove it for few entities but automatically based upon that property value ?

Comment: @SteadyReader, I didn't understand what means 'remove it for few entities'. Look at the use case

Comment: @Dllshod, Yeah got your point, anyways you need an another flag, say it 'IsSoftDelete' in entity iself or somehwere. i.e. assumption would be `firstEntity.IsSoftDelete  = true` and `second.IsSoftDelete = false` And using 'IsSoftDelete' in DeleteEntity method, whether you want remove it or not.

Comment: @SteadyReader, I'm not understanding your comments. I already have IsEntityDeleted flag. Why I need another flag??? Do you understand question?

Comment: @Dllshod, your requirement is when you call this DeleteEntity method on both firstEntity and secondEntity, then for firstEntity is should NOT hard delete item from collection, but for secondEntity it should delete as per use case.  `firstEntity.DeleteEntity(); // entities.Count should be 1

secondEntity.DeleteEntity(); // entities.Count should be 0`   Am i right ?

Comment: @SteadyReader, No, If you see, before calling DeleteEntity of firstEntity count of entities is 2. After, it should decrease. I added this comment in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196617/discussion-between-steadyreader-and-dilshod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are delegating the responsibility of deleting the item from the collection to the entity. This, in my opinion, is wrong, this violates the SOLID principle: Sigle Responsibility. Right now the `MyVirtualCollection` class is responsible for removing items, but it doesn't know about the `DeleteEntity()` method in the `Entity` class. If you want any way to delete the entity from the collection, you should expose an event in the entity class, that advice the collection that she has to actually deletes de entity:

```
delegate void RemoveEventDelegate(Entity entity);
public class Entity
{
    public event RemoveEventDelegate OnEntityDeleted;

    public virtual bool IsEntityDeleted { get; internal set; }

    public void DeleteEntity()
    {
        // Other logics...
        IsEntityDeleted = true;
        if (OnEntityDeleted != null)
        {
            OnEntityDeleted(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And subscribe to the OnEntityDeleted event in the collection

```
public class MyVirtualCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Entity
{
    ICollection<T> Items { get; set; }

    private void Suscribe(Entity entity)
    { 
        Items.Remove(entity);
    }

    public MyVirtualCollection(ICollection<T> source)
    {
        Items = source;
        foreach(var ent in Items)
        {
            ent.OnEntityDeleted += Suscribe;
        }
    }
    public int Count => Items.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => Items.IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
        item.OnEntityDeleted += Suscribe;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach(var ent in Items)
        {
            ent.OnEntityDeleted -= Suscribe;
        }
        Items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return Items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        item.OnEntityDeleted -= Suscribe;
        return Items.Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that when you call the `DeleteEntity()` method, it will delete the entity from ALL the collections it is involved.